# Convert xlsx to csv recursively using bash

Tags: bash, unix

i want to convert xlsx files to csv recursively, the files to be converted will be in .TXT file. need a bash script which will read the file name from .TXT and convert the actual file to csv from its folder itself.

Comment: what machine r u running ?

Answer (score 1):

First conversion command:

```
apt-get install gnumeric
ssconvert file.xlsx convertedfile.csv
```

Recursive conversion:

```
while IFS= read -r f ; do 
  filename="${f%.*}"
  ssconvert ${filename}.xlsx ${filename}.csv
done < listfile.txt
```

Comment: @Cyrus thanks for the suggestion, edited the answer.

Comment: Farhi, When i use ssconvert i am getting the below error,Selected exporter (Gnumeric_stf:stf_csv) does not support saving multiple sheets in one file.

Comment: @MidhunCM well seems like ssconvert doesnt support excel files with multiple sheets, You need to split each shit into a separate file, or find a tool that does this for you.

Comment: The one more issue that i encountered is , the file name having space in it. so the mentioned script giving error like "Unable to guess exporter to use for 'file:" . How to eliminate the space in file name or can we replace the blank space with _?

Comment: @MidhunCM you should set IFS to somthing like `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")`

Comment: #!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DATE=`date +'%d%m%Y'`
Temp_Path=/appinfprd/bi/IA83/IRP/IRPVendors
cd $Temp_Path
#rm INBOUND_XLSX_FILES_*.txt
find /appinfprd/bi/infogix/IA83/InfogixClient/Scripts/IRP/IRPVendors -name "*.xlsx" >> "$Temp_Path/conversion.txt"
while IFS= read -r "f" ; do
  filename="${f%.*}"
ssconvert "${filename}".xls "${filename}".csv
done < conversion.txt
Getting error saying can not convert multiple tabs. please let me know how to convert atleast one tabe.